# How to keep localStorage values after refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, local-storage

This is my ctrl:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function ($window, $scope) {

    $scope.initData = [
        {
            firstName: "John",
            lastName: "Doe",  
        },
        {
            firstName: "Jane",
            lastName: "Doe",
        },
        {
            firstName: "John",
            lastName: "Smith",
        }
    ];

    $window.localStorage.setItem('initData', JSON.stringify($scope.initData));
    $scope.retrievedData = JSON.parse($window.localStorage.getItem('initData'));
    $scope.sortedType = 'firstName';
    $scope.sortedReverse = false;
    //Remove Rows and Update localStorage Key Values
    $scope.removeRow = function(row) {
        $scope.retrievedData.splice(row, 1);
        $scope.initData.splice(row, 1);
        $window.localStorage.setItem('initData', JSON.stringify($scope.initData));
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <span ng-show="sortedType == 'firstName' && sortedReverse" class="fa fa-long-arrow-up"></span>
                        <span ng-show="sortedType == 'firstName' && !sortedReverse" class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></span>
                        <span href="#" ng-click="sortedType = 'firstName'; sortedReverse = !sortedReverse" style="cursor:pointer;">First Name</span>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <span ng-show="sortedType == 'lastName' && sortedReverse" class="fa fa-long-arrow-up"></span>
                        <span ng-show="sortedType == 'lastName' && !sortedReverse" class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></span>
                        <span href="#" ng-click="sortedType = 'lastName'; sortedReverse = !sortedReverse" style="cursor:pointer;">Last Name</span>
                    </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="(k, v) in retrievedData | orderBy: sortedType: sortedReverse">
                <td>{{v.firstName}}</td>
                <td>{{v.lastName}}</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="removeRow();">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Now, I believe it is clear what this does. It is assigning a data from `$scope.initData` to `localStorage` and then interpolate it into the HTML. the function `removeRow()` deletes the row in the table and updates the `localStorage` with the latest action. The issue with this is that each time I reload the HTML the initial `localStorage` data gets loaded and not the updated one. I know that this is because I'm assigning it here: `$window.localStorage.setItem('initData', JSON.stringify($scope.initData))`; but I don't know how to keep it updated after the refresh.

Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Your line `$window.localStorage.setItem('initData', JSON.stringify($scope.initData));` is resetting the data each time you refresh.

Replace the line with this:

```
if(!localStorage.getItem('initData')){
    $window.localStorage.setItem('initData', JSON.stringify($scope.initData));
}
```

More over you should not have that line at all. Start with an empty local storage and add new entries from UI only.

The above code only run it once, for the first time the application is run.

If yo want to re-insert the data every time the list is empty then try following

```
if(!localStorage.getItem('initData') || JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('initData')).length === 0){
    $window.localStorage.setItem('initData', JSON.stringify($scope.initData));
}
```

Comment: I should have this line.. I need to have some initial data, hence the line. :)

Comment: Then you should add the conditional check to see if there is no data then only insert.

Comment: are you still here? There is an issue with this.

Comment: An interesting one.. Your answer is not quite correct, since there is a still key 'initData' only an empty array is a value, that is if all is deleted :)

Comment: yes it will only insert for the first time the application is run. Afterwards when the user clears everything manually from the UI (makes the list empty), I dont think we should re insert the data.

Comment: I'm there, waiting for you.

Comment: Cant join chat, blocked by firewall. I have updated the ans to solve your issue.

Comment: the issue is when an action is repeated. It's only working on the first delete...

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. When I delete it multiple times on refresh the rows are added. If I empty, they are added. Always following the same pattern: delete 3 - 4 are added, delete 2 - 3 are added, delete all - 2 are added

Answer (score 2):

On every page load you are setting new initData and updating the local storage... Instead you should check for existing localstorage data and use that before using the mocked initData

Answer (score 1):

You need to check **first** if your localStorage is empty on load

```
if (localStorage == null) {//setItem() ...};
```

Comment: You mean `if (localStorage == null) {};` ? :)

Comment: yes ! sorry typo; check if your localoStorage is not empty , if it is empty than you can setItem

Answer (score 1):

delete data from local storage using JavaScript 
Here is your code without error passed.

use function for delete

```
       function deleteRow(index){
              dataList.splice(index, 1);
              console.log('====>', dataList)
              localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(dataList)); 
}
```

Comment: its easiest to understand  dataList is array here in this my object is pushed

Comment: items is key name(databaseName)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue for months. And finally I found the solution. ( I am not sure whether this is the same problem for you, anyway sharing my scenario )

When I was testing on my local host, I was using the URL as http://localhost:3000/ for loading the page. But during login, after page refresh,  I was using actually the IP address to redirect the page, which was like http://192.163.1.31:3000/.

So the result, the local storage of http://localhost:3000/ contains the values I saved, but the local storage of http://192.163.1.31:3000/ doesn't contain the values I saved.

So I fixed the solution by simply using same URL across the launch till page load. And the problem was fixed. ( I used http://192.163.1.31:3000/ instead of http://localhost:3000/)

For your case, check whether the URL is different after the page reload.If yes, fix it, and your problem may not persist

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you to understand.....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    var ArrayData = [];
    function clickCounter() {
        if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
            if (localStorage.count) {
                localStorage.count = Number(localStorage.count)+1;
            } else {
                localStorage.count = 1;
            }
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " + localStorage.count;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
        }
    }
    function load()
    {
        var odser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
        document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = odser;
    }
    function fun()
    {
        var odser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
        ArrayData = odser;
        ArrayData.push(3);
        var oser = JSON.stringify(ArrayData);
        localStorage.setItem("data", oser);
        var odser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
        document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = odser;
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="load()">
    <button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button">Click me!</button>
    <button onclick="fun()" type="button">Click me! Array</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <div id="result1"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Simple Steps in matters how you need your page to refresh using afunction to refresh comes handy and effective for me and keeps the locaStorage values set.. i used.... the function below by calling it as load() and it worked for me

```
    function load()
{
  console.log("loading")
  setTimeout("window.location.assign('samepage.html');", 1000);

}
```