# Permanently disable button after on-click

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an e-mail verification page on my project. New users who register will receive an e-mail for them to verify the e-mail. If the link in the e-mail is not clicked after a certain period of time, the page will show a button which they need to click so that they will receive a new e-mail. I would like this button to be permanently disabled after it is clicked, even when the user goes back to the link.

I have added the `[disabled]` property to the button and set it to true after on-click. But when the page is refreshed or revisited, the button will not be disabled.

This is my HTML so far:

```
<button type="button" 
    class="btn btn-primary" 
    [disabled]="clicked" 
    (click)=resendEmail()>
        Resend Verification E-mail
</button>
```

In my .ts:

```
resendEmail() {
  this.clicked = true;
}
```

Comment: On page refresh, of course the value will not persist, you may need to use `localStorage`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava even with local storage, if the user clears it or is in incognito mode, it won't work. This kind of control is made on the server, then sent to the client.

Comment: If you want the clicked state to persist after refresh, you'll have to store it using local variables or cookies when the button is clicked, and then check these and update the 'clicked' state in your component as appropriate when the page loads.

Comment: @trichetriche Yes, or that.

Comment: It's difficult to say without knowing more about the situation, but I'd say storing this sort of information (e.g. when a button has been clicked) on a server is overkill. You might store the registration status of a user and then adjust your page accordingly, but for a state like this, local storage feels likely to be the best solution.

Comment: @mhfour - this might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564795/how-to-keep-localstorage-values-after-refresh

Comment: If you use accounts I assume you also store them somewhere, there you can add a field in which you store whether the verification email has been sent to a specific e-mail address. In the onInit you can retrieve that value and use it in your html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick fix, you can use localStorage

```
this.clicked = localStorage.getItem('clickedVerificationMail') !== null;
if (! this.clicked) {
    localStorage.setItem('clickedVerificationMail', true);
    this.clicked = true;
}
```

As a general rule, everything that you really want to enforce or security related belongs on your server. Javascript is easily changeable by a user.