# Keep data on main page even after page refresh that are stored in JS localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage, page-refresh, session-storage

When i refresh my page the data remains in localstorage even after refresh, but it removes from the main page, how to keep it there on main document page!!

Comment: Reinitialize your data from localstorage, in the same way you initialized it at the first time.

Comment: @Ajeet Shah Can you show me a little example focusing on main problem solution!!

Comment: Check [How to keep localStorage values after refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44564795/2873538)